# Help me implementing addClassName in my JavaScript project the right way

Tags: javascript, dom

I find myself often needing addClassName and removeClassName functions for `Element`s. However, I dare not to extend the native `Element` due to potential collisions. So, now I am wondering what to do.

I took a look at ExtJS, and it achieves this like:

```
var element = document.getElementById('...');
var elem = new Ext.Element(element);
elem.addClass('something');
```

I like the idea of not extending the native `Element` here, but I do not really like the idea of wrapping the element so hard over a custom object, because now I can't do several things like `setAttribute` easily, for example:

```
var element = document.getElementById('...');
var elem = new Ext.Element(element);
elem.addClass('something');
elem.setAttribute('src', '...'); // Fails
```

However, I could do:

```
var element = document.getElementById('...');
element.setAttribute('src', '...');
var elem = new Ext.Element(element);
elem.addClass('something');
```

but to me this does not look really nice. It looks a bit complex instead.

Are there any other alternative ways I could use besides wrapping the element around my own object that offers me these cool methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if there's already an implementation defined. I'm pretty sure `addClassName` is not going to have a different signature than you have at the moment.

```
if (!node.prototype.addClassName) {
    node.prototype.addClassName = function addClassName(name) {
        // your code
    }
}
```